# Can you identify this aircraft?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification

This photo, taken circa 1939, was taken of my uncle's aircraft at Roosevelt Field on Long Island, New York.  Lotar Munch and his partner operated "Munch & Romeo Flying Service" out of Hanger 32. I'm trying to learn more about his business and his aircraft as well.  Note the registration number "NC966V."  I have learned that the "C" indicated that it was a commercial registration. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: NC966V - Roosevelt Field, NY]

[image: Second photo]

Comment: https://1000aircraftphotos.com/Contributions/Shumaker/12098.htm  (Even the same tail number:  Its a Westbrook W-5 Sportster)

Comment: http://all-aero.com/index.php/56-planes-v-w/17398-westbrook-aeronautical-w-5-westbrook-aeronautical-sportster

Comment: P.S. All I did was google the tail NC996V, and follow the first half-dozen links.
I'm sure you could've done that yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some have written in the comments, it is a Westbrook W-5-B Sportster.

Westbrook started as a company in 1929 and failed in 1931. Approximately five W-5 sportsters have been built:

1. [NC9N] c/n 501 destroyed in a 1931 crash
2. [853W] c/n 502,
3. [NC966V] c/n 503 lost in a 1938 accident
4. [NC92V] c/n 504,
5. possibly unlicensed one,  c/n 505,

<sub>source / further info: [aerofiles.com](http://aerofiles.com/_wa.html) / [secretprojects.co.uk](https://www.secretprojects.co.uk/threads/westbrook-sportster.21196/) / [all-aero.com](http://all-aero.com/index.php/56-planes-v-w/17398-westbrook-aeronautical-w-5-westbrook-aeronautical-sportster)</sub>

---

### Munch & Romeo, Inc

The aircraft was shown on the business card of Munch and Romeo, which also shows the prices they charged for flight instruction:

[image: Business card of Munch & Romea]

I found evidence that one of the aircraft of Munch and Romeo was  involved in a mid-air collision in 1936:

> #### Negligence -Collision -Insufficient Allegation of Agency.
>
> -[NewYork]  In an action for damages arising out of a collision between
> the plaintiff's airplane with that of the defendant as both were about
> to land,the complaint alleged that the defendant's plane was being
> operated by one Donahue with the consent and permission of the
> defendant, and that the collision was caused solely by Donahue's
> negligence. On motion to dismiss the complaint for failure to state a
> cause of action, held: complaint dismissed, with leave to plaintiff
> to serve an amended complaint within ten days.There were no
> allegations that Donahue was operating the defendant's airplane as
> his agent, servant or employee, or in the defendant's business
> and within the scope of his employment. None will be inferred from the
> allegation that the defendant was the owner of and in control of the
> airplane.An allegation that Donahue was operating the vehicle with
> defendant's con-sent and permission would be sufficient to charge the
> latter in a case arising out of an automobile collision on a public
> highway under §59 of the Vehicle and Traffic law, but the statute is
> not applicable here. Consequently the common law rule governs, by which
> it is settled in New York that the owner of a vehicle will not be held
> liable for negligence of its operator unless at the time it was being
> used in the owner's business by the operator within the scope of his
> employment. Munch & Romeo, Inc. v. Caton, 96 N. Y. L. J.876, 235 C. C.
> H. 1213 (County Court, Nassau County, New York, Sept. 25,1936).

<sub>source: Journal of Air Law and Commerce, Volume 8|Issue 1, Article  8 [scholar.smu.edu](https://scholar.smu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://aviation.stackexchange.com/&httpsredir=1&article=3943&context=jalc)</sub>

---

The company owned other aircraft as well; by 1936 they seemed to be active in aircraft trading as they tried to sell several aircraft in advertisements in [Aero Digest, Volume 29 of July 193](https://archive.org/stream/aerodigest2919unse/aerodigest2919unse_djvu.txt)6

> AERONCA C-3: New September 1935; 150 hours  total time ; just top
> overhauled, A-l condition  throughout, SI. 425. Munch & Romeo, Inc.,
> Hangar  7, Roosevelt Field, Mineola, New York.

> 1936 TAYLOR CUB: 2 months old, 35 hours total  time, \$1,195. Gee Bee,
> Kinner K-5: 45 hours since  overhaul, \$875. Avian Cirrus, \$600. Also
> Great Lakes,  Birds, Cessnas, Monocoupes. Munch & Romeo, Inc.,  Hangar
> 7, Roosevelt Field 1 , Mineola, New York.